# Fix a table cell's height

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, what I want to do is have a list within a cell that has items added to it and after it reaches a certain height, stop it and have a scroll bar appear. How can I create a td with a fixed height? So far I have:

```
<tr>
  <td valign='top' height="200px" border="1">
    <ul id="travelList" align='left'></ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put your `<ul>` inside a div that has overflow auto and max-height. Like this:

```
<tr>
  <td valign="top" border="1">
    <div style="overflow:auto;max-height:200px">
      <ul id="travelList" align="left"></ul>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could I not just put the max-height and overflow onto the ul?

Comment: @Jupiter Why not try that yourself?!

Comment: Haha I just did and that works perfectly!! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
style="max-height:200px"
```

note: not tested, but this is where you'd start, so google CSS max-height to get more detail of how heights work.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work, the list just keeps going, is there a way to make it a fixed table and anything over creates a scroll bar? Kind of like a window.

Comment: what do you mean by "the list keeps going" (just trying to get a clear picture of what you've got).

Comment: Like, it overflows the max-height, so instead of a scrollbar being created it just keeps adding an element to the bottom, but I figured it out, I just needed an overflow